# Manually ACK batch AMQP messages

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, batching

I'm able to receive batch messages with the codes below. But now my question is, how should I manually ACK the messages. ACK all the messages in the list one by one, or ACK the last message in the list is enough?   Thanks in advance!

```
public class MyMessageListener implements ChannelAwareBatchMessageListener {

@Override
public void onMessageBatch(List<Message> messages, Channel channel){

//Do something......
    
//option 1    
 messages.forEach(msg-> channel.basicAck(msg.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), true); 

//option 2
channel.basicAck( messages.get(messages.size()-1).getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), true);
        
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your business case , generally speaking acknowledging all the messages will increase the network traffic and consequently your message throughput will go down .

The second option is a pragmatic approach provided it is OK to have the possibility of loosing some intermediate messages which may not have been delivered and a later message is delivered and acknowledged in which case the un-delivered messages will also get ackéd .

So it is a design decision which is driven by the sensitivity of payload of your messages.